# Difference between BGA and LGA

Tags: pcb

I have come across a chip which is only available in [LGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_grid_array). I wouldn't touch [BGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array), but what about LGA? How possible is it to design for one with little experience? Are there any gotchas? I'm planning to reflow solder these using a hot plate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LGA is similar to BGA, but without the solder balls, so you have to apply solder paste to the pads with a stencil. I don't think you will find them any easier to use than BGA.

Comment: Is it any comparison to QFN?

Comment: Quite different. I can solder QFN parts with a soldering station, quite easily.

Comment: It's LGA pads/balls/whatever around the edges only though, which makes me draw a comparison to QFN. It's an LSM303 accelerometer / magnetometer.

Comment: that package looks like a cross between a QFN and a LGA.  Basically its a QFN with leads that don't wrap around and are pushed in from the package edge just slightly.  You won't be soldering that with an iron but i don't think it would be too difficult with a board heater and a hot air soldering unit. Or paste and a hot plate / baker.  You shouldn't have the settling issues that would normally occur with a 'regular' LGA.

Answer (score 2):

I've done LGA on a hot plate before, but only with a stencil. I wouldn't try it without a stencil. If this is a one-off, why not try the LSM303 breakout from Sparkfun?

Comment: Where do you get (or how do you make) your stencils?  I imagine that you're not doing huge quantities if you're using a hot plate.

Comment: I etch my own stencils at home with a kit from Rena Electronics.

Answer (score 1):

I've done an LGA without a stencil. But that was a small low pad count part (BMA180). I had to tin the pads with flux and solder, then placed the chip on top, then used hot air reflow to solder it.